# Cucumber report duplication while using Scenario Outline

Tags: maven, jvm, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

When using **Scenario Outline**, the report generates two times of scenario, one without color and another with color (as show in the image).

This happens only when using **Scenario Outline**, not when using *Scenario*.

Here is my *pom.xml*
'
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    GroupMaven
    ArtifactMaven
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    pom
    ProjectMaven
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

'

Here is My Cucumber Runner class

'

> @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
>   @CucumberOptions(format = {"html:cucumber-html-reports/first",
>           "json:cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" }, features = { "test/features/FirstFeature.feature" })
>   public class CucumberCukesTest {
>   }
>   '

And i used monochrome,strict,dryrum, etc options, nothing will work. And also i used **plugin** instead of **format**.

[Cucumber report for scenario using Scenario Outline keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGf8p.png)

Comment: try using [qaf gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) it generate very [descriptive report](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the generalized details of your scenario outline ie what you have written in the feature file. Check out the  and  in the 6th and 7th step.

The second one and others depending on the number of examples is the scenario with the details substituted with the actual values for userid and password. Notice the absence of <> in the same steps.

Comment: Ok, but i dont want the first one in the output cucumber report, only i want the second one(colored) in the report. How can i configure for it?

Comment: I do not know if there is any option to configure it. Look at modifying the source code to your requirements. Or you could look at using a reporting tool.